# Coordinate of point, given a line segment

Tags: analytic-geometry

It is given that points A = (−2, 1)  B = (4, −1) form a segment, and it is asked at which point in y axis
(when x = 0) when you "look at" or draw segments to points A and B there is a 90 degree angle.
How do you solve this?
The answer is 0,3 and 0,-3 but I cant understand how to find them.

I added a picture, it is known that x = 0, and is asked y coordinate, and the angle between red lines is 90. what is the coordinate of point c?

> [image: Picture of problem]

Comment: Use distance formula and Pythagoras theorem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales'_theorem

Comment: So we are making the assumption here that the 90 degree angle must be at C? Because if the angle is allowed at A or B, there are more options. It is not explicitly clear to me that the angle must be at C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, might not be the best way, using the fact that the product of the slope of perpendicular line is $-1$.

Let $A(-2,1)$, $B(4,-1)$ and $C(0,c)$ be three points. First, the slope of the line between $A$ and $C$ is
$$m_1=\frac{c-1}{0-(-2)} = \frac{c-1}{2}$$
Second, the slope of the line between $B$ and $C$ is
$$m_2=\frac{c-(-1)}{0-4} = \frac{c+1}{-4}$$
The product of the slopes must be $-1$
$$m_1\times m_2=\frac{c-1}{2}\times\frac{c+1}{-4} = \frac{c^2-1}{-8} = -1$$
This gives a quadratic equation
$$c^2-1=8$$
which gives
$$c=\pm3$$